# Autoref with optional argument

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, optional-arguments, autoref

Something I have always wanted to do is use `\autoref` with an optional argument, similarly to the use that is often made of `\cite`: I would like to be able to write `\autoref[comment]{label}`, to obtain [link to label, comment] in the final pdf. Is there any way of doing this (specifically with autoref, and not the other referencing packages/commands)? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See three different versions below (due to change requests by the O.P.)

With `xparse` it is very easy to redefine some commands, provided the original version of `\autoref` is stored as well, this requires `\LetLtxMacro` from `letltxmacro` package.

Since `\autoref` has a starred version `\autoref*` this has to be captured as well.

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{...}
```

redefines `\autoref` and providing a starred first argument, (s), an optional (o) 2nd argument (for the comment) and the mandatory (m) 3rd argument which is meant for the label name.

With `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{}` the calling of the starred version can be checked and with `\IfValueTF{#2}{}{}` the specification of an optional argument can be checked.

Please note that the comment is not wrapped in the hyperlink box/frame!
If this is required, more has work to be done.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \autoreforig*{#3}\IfValueT{#2}{#2}%
    }{%
      \autoreforig{#3}\IfValueT{#2}{#2}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

See \autoref[ is very nice]{section:foo} or \autoref*[ is nice too]{section:foobar}

\section{Foo section}\label{section:foo}

\section{Foo bar section}\label{section:foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with square brackets**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    [%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \autoreforig*{#3}% 
    }{%
      \autoreforig{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueT{#2}{,\space#2}]%
  }
}


\begin{document}

See \autoref[is very nice]{section:foo} or \autoref*[is nice too]{section:foobar}

\section{Foo section}\label{section:foo}

\section{Foo bar section}\label{section:foobar}

\end{document}
```

Third installment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    \IfValueT{#2}{[}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \autoreforig*{#3}% 
    }{%
      \autoreforig{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueT{#2}{,\space#2]}%
  }
}


\begin{document}

See \autoref[is very nice]{section:foo} or \autoref*[is nice too]{section:foobar}, but \autoref{section:foo} or \autoref*{section:foobar} are without comment. 

\section{Foo section}\label{section:foo}

\section{Foo bar section}\label{section:foobar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't familiar with letltxmacro or xparse. Are you able to include the square brackets, and possibly eliminate the need for the leading space in the comment? I.e. I would like `\autoref[is very nice]{section:foo}` to produce [section 1, is very nice].

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: The square brackets are no problem. But shall the link border wrap around them or only `section 1` be the link?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would just like "section 1" to be the link in [section 1, is very nice] (this would mimic the behaviour of `\cite[Theorem 1]{reference}`).

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: See the update at the end of my post

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: You're welcome! Happy TeXing

Comment: one last thing! It appears the square brackets appear even when the optional argument is not inserted. Is there any way to only have them if there is an optional argument? **Edit**: one can just use `\autoreforig`

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: See the next update ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided and great answer seems to be broken by TeXlive 2023. Any idea what's causing the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: It seems the issue is with \LetLtxMacro... defining a \myautoref as above without the use of \LetLtxMacro works for me. It's simply that I cannot create a copy of original \autoref to be used in a redefinition with the same name... :-o

Comment: @yogik `\autoref` has changed. You need `\NewCommandCopy\autoreforig\autoref` to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution for new LaTeX from TeXlive 2023/etc. onward:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \NewCommandCopy\autoreforig\autoref
   \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
         \hyperref[#3]%
      }{%
         \autoreforig*{#3}\IfValueT{#2}{\nobreak}\xspace\IfValueT{#2}{#2}%
      }%
   }
}
```

Kudos to Ulrike Fischer and David Carlisle for their quick response!