# Autoref with optional argument text *in generated link*

Tags: hyperref, links, optional-arguments, autoref, hyperlink

Related to [Autoref with optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422029/autoref-with-optional-argument), I would like to define an (optional) argument to \autoref that appears after the regular autoref printout, but within the actual link that is generated by \autoref.

I.e., the command

```
\autoref[(left inset)]{fig:somefigure}
```

should produce a hyperref link with the complete text being active

> ... Figure 1 (left inset) ...

Is that possible in a generic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to always use a non-link reference and then separately adding the hyperlink: (example copied from Christian Hupfers answer to the original question)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
      \hyperref[#3]%
    }%
    {%
      \autoreforig*{#3}\IfValueT{#2}{#2}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

See \autoref[ is very nice]{section:foo} or \autoref*[ is nice too]{section:foobar}

\section{Foo section}\label{section:foo}

\section{Foo bar section}\label{section:foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great – thank you Marcel!  For completeness, I've added an `\xspace` to automatically get the space between regular and optional argument –> `\autoreforig*{#3}\xspace\IfValueT{#2}{#2}`

Comment: Note: Don't miss the `%` or it will include whitespaces.